# Slideshow not working in IE for Windows

Tags: javascript

Any idea as to why this is happening?
Works in Chrome, and Firefox but not in IE. 
Is there a script I can use to fix this?

Problem:
http://www.isomham.com/TEST/hospitality/hamptoninn-murrellsinlet.html

Answer (score 0):

Checked it in IE and I get this error:

```
Message: 'imagearray[...].0' is null or not an object
Line: 34
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.isomham.com/TEST/Scripts/simplegallery.js
```

Fixing that should do it

EDIT:

Actually it think that the code:

```
var mygallery=new simpleGallery({...etc
```

needs to be wrapped around:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var mygallery=new simpleGallery({...etc
});
```

I think the script is trying to look for #simplegallery1 before the page has finished loading.